# centering the text box using margin auto

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-ui

- I am trying to make the search box to be center.
- so I gave   marginLeft: "auto",marginRight: "auto", to the class search
- but its not centering.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-xu3ld

```or-tag-here
search: {
    marginLeft: "auto",
    marginRight: "auto",
    textAlign: "center"
  }

export default function CustomizedInputBase() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.search}>
      <Paper className={classes.root}>
        <IconButton className={classes.iconButton} aria-label="Menu">
          <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <InputBase
          className={classes.input}
          placeholder="Search Google Maps"
          inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Search Google Maps" }}
        />
        <IconButton className={classes.iconButton} aria-label="Search">
          <SearchIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Divider className={classes.divider} />
        <IconButton
          color="primary"
          className={classes.iconButton}
          aria-label="Directions"
        >
          <DirectionsIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why not use flexbox or grid layout for the content container? That would come to be simpler, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

See [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-sbxy9).

If you look at the generated HTML for your example, you'll see that the `div` you put the `search` class on IS centered, but the actual search element WITHIN the div is NOT centered.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your search in another div with class 'wrapper'

```
<div className={classes.wrapper}>
      <div className={classes.search}>
        <Paper className={classes.root}>
          <IconButton className={classes.iconButton} aria-label="Menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <InputBase
            className={classes.input}
            placeholder="Search Google Maps"
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Search Google Maps" }}
          />
          <IconButton className={classes.iconButton} aria-label="Search">
            <SearchIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Divider className={classes.divider} />
          <IconButton
            color="primary"
            className={classes.iconButton}
            aria-label="Directions"
          >
            <DirectionsIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Paper>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and make the following changes to your css.

```
  search: {
    textAlign: "center",
    display: "inline-block"
  },
  wrapper: {
    textAlign: "center",
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to center an element.
Instead of using marginLeft and marginRight auto you can use this code

search: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent:"center"
  }

which will center your element